# Gmod Wiremod not saving and/or loading correctly

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

I have wiremod, wiremod extras, and numerous other addons in gmod. When I load a game saved via the "save" command, I am unable to select inputs and outputs using the wire tool, disabling me from working on anything I was doing earlier. I did notice however the debugger works fine. When saving, there are no script errors. I understand the possibility of mod confliction, however I have tried this with different combinations of mods, and I also have not noticed this problem in the past. In addition, I need certain mods enabled for what I am creating. I looked online for quite some time, and the only other person I was able to find with the same problem had a different version of wire, and a version switch was ultimately his solution. Does anybody know a way to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it happen with everything but wiremod disabled as well? You should at least try to narrow down the issue, even if you need the other mods. Updating/switching between versions is always a good idea, not just for wire.

Comment: I disabled everything else (note I used addon manager) and tried. The problem persisted and I got some console errors: https://pastebin.com/BTYjdt29

Comment: This really looks like an issue with wiremod itself.. maybe try a different (older) version of it

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Duplicator tool, or the [Advanced Duplicator](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=773402917) tool if you have it if you want to save your wire contraptions.